# Testing download speed using iperf

Tags: iperf

I am using iperf to test my bandwidth. But I am not getting whether it is showing my upload or download speed. Say, I have two PCs A and B. If I want to test how fast I can download a file to A from B, where should I run the server i.e "iperf -s" ? on A or B ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

With  the iperf3 you can use the `-R` option to send the traffic from Server to client.

```
  -R, Reverse test mode – Server sends, client receives
```

Answer (score 2):

Traffic way is from client to server.

From manpage:

To perform an iperf test the user must
       establish both a **server (to discard traffic)** and a **client (to generate traffic)**

Comment: There's a great gui to Iperf that can be found at http://code.google.com/p/xjperf/

Answer (score 0):

It's from to.

So if you run the listen daemon on B, and connect via A thats testing the TX performance from A to B, simply do it the other way around to test the connection back.

Answer (score 0):

With [iperf 2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/) on can use --reverse or -R (for non-windows) to reverse the traffic and get through a NAT firewall.  Iperf 2 also supports --full-duplex for same socket full duplex traffic. The options of -d or --dualtest will provide two sockets (but won't pierce a NAT firewall so one has to either remove it or configure port forwarding.) The - r or --tradeoff will serialize the upstream then the downstream.

One can use --bounceback for latency testing and --bounceback-congest for latency testing while there is a "working load." This hasn't been released yet so one has to compile the master branch from source.

[See man page for more](https://iperf2.sourceforge.io/iperf-manpage.html)